# Can I run a script with LispWorks, like with SBCL's "--script" option?

Tags: common-lisp, lispworks

I mean with SBCL I can run a script as easy as `sbcl --script piece-of-code.lisp`. But I can't find an obvious way to do so with LispWorks. Of course there's always a deploy and run option, but it requires a build script for every little exercise.

Is there a way to run a script with LispWorks without building an executable or running it from listener manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you create lispworks console, like in: 
http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/LW/html/lw-177.htm#83244

Then, you can use `lw-console -init foo.lisp` without IDE.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: use function `save-image` LispWorks require LICENSE, details [here](http://www.lispworks.com/products/lispworks.html#personal)

Answer (score 2):

The `sbcl --script` is to make sbcl aware the first line of your code might be #!/usr/bin/sbcl ... and LispWorks doesn't seem to have that.

However, if you just want to run a script and not make it executable, then you can write:

```
lispworks -init my-lisp-init
```

And it will load `my-lisp-init.lisp` if I understood [the documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/RNIG/html/readme-241.htm) right

Comment: @akalenuk Any reason why you can't develop in LispWorks and use CLISP or SBCL to get the desired behaviour? It would be a nice way to test if you're making compatible code.

Comment: The sole reason why I got into LispWorks is CAPI.

Answer (score 2):

The various command line option for the latest LispWorks 6.1 are described here:

http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/LW/html/lw-517.htm#pgfId-891723

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't has anything like "run script", so I thought, maybe I just don't understand how to use it. Say, "-environment" key indirectly states that there is a scenario for running something without showing the environment itself. But I tried "-load" and above mentioned "-init" and with no luck so far. Every time the environment shows, but script, working ok from it by "Compile and Load" menu option, doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @akalenuk: You see the `eval` option? Just pass code that `load`s a file. How about the `load` option? Or the `init` option?